# What is the right way to implement the graph of validation process of Batch Normalization in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, normalization

When using **Batch Normalization** we can use the **batch mean** and **batch variance** during training.
However this fails to give good enough results in **validation** case. We get the best results by providing the **population mean** and **population variance**.

However this means that the two graphs will be almost identical except the part where we need to subtract the mean and divide the standard deviation (we use the population ones)

Our current implementation worked ok but it includes too much **boilerplate code**.

*Note that in other frameworks you can extract and manipulate layers of a model quite easily for such cases, but tensorflow has an only append policy to its graphs*

What is the optimal way to go in such cases where one graph is slightly different from the other?